# Swift documentation comment @code equivalent.

Tags: ios, swift, documentation-generation

I am aware about Swift documentation comment and many of its tags that are used to document code like :param:, :return: etc.

But I am not able to find or figure out @code Objective-C documentation comment equivalent for Swift. I want to include some code example in the description of some class in my open source project but I am not sure how to do that.

Could anyone please shed some light on how to do that or that is even possible at this stage?

Comment: What tool are you using for documenting your code?

Comment: @JamesWebster I will be using appledocs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc), you just need to indent your code 4 spaces

```
/*!
Documentation for the class.

Here is a code sample

    func code()
    {
        //code
    }
*/
```

You'll notice that a `lot` *of* ***the*** *formatting* options are similar to Stack Overflow! They both use [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) for formatting.

I just happen to have documented a project using appledoc for the first time so I have a few of the pages in recent history. The `code` feature is documented [here](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/wiki/appledoc-docs-comments)

---

Regarding your question about `:code: @code` syntax options. Appledoc directives accept any non-whitespace-character followed by a keyword. To Xcode, documenation is ***just a comment***.

> Directives prefix: Although all directives in examples above use "@" sign as a prefix, you can actually use any non-whitespace char instead, for example \param, $param, %param and so on...

<sup><sup>[[Source]](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/wiki/appledoc-docs-comments)</sup></sup>

It does seem however, that the common `@code` isn't supported by appledoc the way it is by other documentation tools like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

Comment: Will Xcode accept this format? As I could see from the link it uses @param etc but Xcode uses :param: in Swift.

Comment: To Xcode, documentation is ***just*** a comment. Appledoc directives accept any non-whitespace-character followed by a keyword. I'll update my answer with more information.

Answer (score 1):

as per the reference of [here](http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/) you can write documentation for code block as per below.

```
/**
    The area of the `Shape` instance.

    Computation depends on the shape of the instance. For a triangle, `area` will be equivalent to:

      let height = triangle.calculateHeight()
      let area = triangle.base * height / 2
*/
var area: CGFloat { get }
```